# PHP mail does not send the mail and no error

Tags: php, email, pear-mail

I'm using this codes and this does not give me any error and does not send any mail.
Is there any notable issue with this? 
and it doesnt send via the SMTP details i gave.
Im doing everything manually.

Could someone rewrite this codes to work with SMTP and the mistake I have done?

```
<?php 
    require_once "Mail.php"; 
    $Subject=T rim(stripslashes($_POST[ 'Subject']));
    $Name=T rim(stripslashes($_POST[ 'Name'])); 
    $Email=T rim(stripslashes($_POST[ 'Email']));
    $EmailMe='admin@mail.com' ; 
    $Message=T rim(stripslashes($_POST[ 'Message']));
    $smtp=M ail::factory( 'smtp', 
    array( 'host'=> 'host', 
            'port' => '#port', 
            'auth' => true, 
            'username' => 
            'mymail@mail.com', 
            'password' => '********'
            )); 

$mail_user = "<html>
<body style='font-size: 120%;'>
    <table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style='background:#e1f5fe;'>
        <tr>
            <td align='left' style='background:#2196F3;padding-left:5px;'><img src='path/to/image.png' width='50px' align='center' alt='' /><span style='color:#fff;font-size:20px;margin-top:5px;'>Title</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </td>
        <tr>
            <td style='padding-left:5%;padding-right:5%'>
                <p>Hi $Name,</p>
                <p style='padding-left:3%;'>body for users</p>
                <div style='background:#b3e5fc;'>
                    <p style='padding-left:1%;'>Message : </p>
                    <p style='padding-left:2%;padding-bottom:2px;'>$Message</p>
                </div>
                <p>Regards,</p>
                <p style=''><b>Admin</b>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
</body>

</html>"; 

$mail_me = "<html>

<body style='font-size: 120%;'>
    <table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style='background:#e1f5fe;'>
        <tr>
            <td align='left' style='background:#2196F3;padding-left:5px;'><img src='path/to/image.png' width='50px' align='center' alt='' /><span style='color:#fff;font-size:20px;margin-top:5px;'>Titile</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </td>
        <tr>
            <td style='padding-left:5%;padding-right:5%'>
                <p>Hi $Name,</p>
                <p style='padding-left:3%;'>body for me</p>
                <div style='background:#b3e5fc;'>
                    <p style='padding-left:1%;'>Message : </p>
                    <p style='padding-left:2%;padding-bottom:2px;'>$Message</p>
                </div>
                <p>Regards,</p>
                <p style=''><b>Admin</b>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        $Email
    </table>
    <br>
</body>

</html>"; 
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n"; 
 $headers .= "From: ME <mymail@mail.com> \r\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To:
    <admin@mail.com> \r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Return-Path: mymail@mail.com";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP \r\n";
    $success =  mail($Email, $Subject, $mail_user, $headers); 
                mail($EmailMe, $Subject, $mail_me, $headers); 
        if ($success){ print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=/thanks\">";
        } 
        else{ 
        print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=/error\">"; 
        }
```

Comment: What webserver this code your running?

Comment: Are you trying to run this script on a server or on localhost ?

Comment: @mrid  not on a localhost. My server is shared hosting from Googie Host.

Comment: sending email have many steps , php mail() function just will do first step and if it could do it successfully it wont return any error.   you should check your mail server log if it was not sent or received.